# Searching for artist name and song from a file in C++

Tags: c++

I have written some code for the search function in *C++* to find artist name and song. My code doesn't seem to work. A message displays that the artist and song is found and then the menu repeats itself infinite times.

My full program code is as below.

```
#include "Music.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void Music::menu()
{
    int input;

    do {
        cout << "Select an option from the menu" << endl;
        cout << "1. Display records" << endl;
        cout << "2. Search for records" << endl;
        cout << "3. Writing records to a file" << endl;
        cin >> input;

        switch (input) {
        case 1:
            displayfile();
            break;

        case 2:
            searchrecords();
            break;

        case 3:
            writefile();
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Invalid option entered. Try again" << endl;
            menu();
        }
    } while (input != 4);
}

void Music::displayfile()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("Music.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open()) {

        while (getline(myfile, line)) {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    }
}

void Music::writefile()
{
    ofstream write;
    write.open("Music.txt", ofstream::app);

    if (write.is_open()) {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Enter a title of song to the playlist" << endl;
        cin.getline(title, 255).get();

        write << " " << title;

        cout << "Enter the artist of the song to playlist" << endl;
        cin.getline(artist, 255).get();

        write << " " << artist;

        cout << "Enter the year of the song" << endl;
        cin >> year;

        write << "" << year;

        cout << "Enter the duration of the song" << endl;
        cin >> duration;

        write << " " << duration;

        cout << "Writing to a file is successful" << endl;

    }
    else {
        cout << "File couldn't be open" << endl;
    }
    write.close();
    displayfile();
}

bool Music::searchrecords()
{
    bool found = true;
    string search;

    string line;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("Music.txt");

    cout << "Enter the artist you want to search for: " << endl;
    getline(cin, search).get();

    cout << "Enter for the song you want to search for: " << endl;
    getline(cin, search).get();

    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (!myfile.eof()) {
            if (found) {

                cout << "The artist is found" << search << endl;
                cout << "The song is found" << search << endl;
                return found;

            }
            else {

                cout << "The artist is not found" << endl;
                return false;


            }
            getline(myfile, line);

            myfile.close();
            displayfile();
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate it if you could help me as I am stuck on what to do.

Comment: learn to use your debugger

Answer (score 1):

1. You have `bool found = true;` right in the beginning of `Music::searchrecords` function, so the first iteration of looking through file immediately returns.
2. You do `getline(cin, search).get();` twice in a row, while apparently you want to read in two different `string` variables, one for artist, one for song
3. You do a loop with this `if` on each iteration

```
            if (found) {
                cout << "The artist is found" << search << endl;
                cout << "The song is found" << search << endl;
                return found;
            }
            else {
                cout << "The artist is not found" << endl;
                return false;
            }
```

In both cases you terminate your function by calling `return`, so the very first iteration of looking through file returns from function (you don't read the file completely)

4. You call

```
myfile.close();
displayfile();
```

on each iteration, so even if you hadn't had your `if` right above, then your program would crash anyway, because you close file **inside** the loop that's iterating over it.

5. You don't compare `line` to check if you indeed found your song

In total, your program doesn't work at all, and StackOverflow isn't a forum to completely write the entire program instead of you. So you better use a debugger in your IDE to see what your program does step by step, or take a piece of paper and a pen to write down how you would accomplish your task